# git status shows staged files but git commit says nothing to commit

Tags: git

I added into stage a lot of files (renamed, deleted and new files).

When I do git status, I have a lot of files staged to be commited in green, but when I do git commit, it says there is nothing to commit... What is wrong? I hope I will not lose my changes.

```
git status
On branch develop
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   docs/file1
        new file:   docs/file2
        new file:   docs/file3
        modified:   webapp/file1.py
        modified:   webapp/file2.py
        # ETC...


git commit -m "Commit message"
On branch develop
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

If I do git log, I see my commit but it is weird that I still see my files in stage when I do git status.

```
git log
commit 3a2b50f1f48912fc156504b82328fdcc3d6e2333
Author: Mike
Date:   Tue Oct 7 15:28:06 2014 -0500

    Commit message
```

Comment: It sure looks like your `git commit` actually happened, and then immediately after that you (or something on behalf of you) ran *another* git command that gave you the "nothing to commit" message.  Do you have some aliases and/or shell magic and/or commit hooks active?

Comment: no I do not have some aliases or shell magic. I actually was able to get the situation back to the normal by trying to perfomr some unstage/stage commands again. Hopefully I have not lost anything.